# How do I delete an unnecessary account in Trello?

Tags: account-management, trello

I created 2 Trello accounts, both with same email, one by logging in and the second by using Google Apps with same email, how do I ditch one of them?

> **Related:**
>   [How do I delete my Trello account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20343/how-do-i-delete-my-trello-account)

Comment: @phwd, *this* question isn't a duplicate.  The *other* one is.

Comment: @Kyralessa If one end is a duplicate then the next is its duplicate. It doesn't really matter which way the closure goes. There is an official answer from a Trello employee, Rich Armstrong, on the next one as well

Comment: @phwd, then I guess the "earlier" text below needs to be corrected.

Comment: @Kyralessa I reopened it, honestly it's indifferent to me

Answer (score 9):

I think you probably don't need to.

I did the same thing, because I didn't notice the Google option at first.  When I logged in with Google later, it showed me the same information as with my original account.

Just to make sure, I logged out, then logged in with my original account (Gmail address and Trello password), and it showed me the same information.  Apparently if you use the same e-mail address, it automatically associates the two.

Comment: no I have two different ones.. one with username firstinitial/lastname, the second with username firstname/lastname and both with same email... they have different groups.. I thought trello had dropped all my groups and lists at first ;)

Comment: @tom, have you tried changing them to show the exact same name?  (if that's feasible)

Comment: I have the same problem. Everything looks identical (email) and they still seem to be two different accounts.